# How to troubleshoot force-enabling multi-process support with Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to learn what is preventing my install of Firefox from using multi-process functionality (also called "Electrolysis" or "e10s"). Mozilla's wiki gives instructions on [how to force enable multi-process windows](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Force_Enable) and I have already changed `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` and `browser.tabs.remote.force-enable` to 'true'.

Checking **about:support** I see the message "Multiprocess Windows  0/1 (Disabled by add-ons)"

[image: about:support screenshot]

However this message persists even after restarting Firefox with all add-ons disabled. I have taken the additional step of checking [arewee10syet.com](https://www.arewee10syet.com/) and if the data on that site is correct, all my extensions are compatible already.

How can I troubleshoot this further, and discover what is preventing me from enabling this feature?

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Modifications add-on is blocking multiprocess windows:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubufox/+bug/1627290

To disable it: In `about:addons` click on the *Extensions* category, find the **Ubuntu Modifications** add-on and click its *Disable* button. Restart Firefox and then go to `about:support`. The status of *Multiprocess Windows* should now read "1/1 (Enabled by user)".

Comment: I tried this early on, however the [duplicate bug listed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubufox/+bug/1627808) mentions `extensions.e10sBlockedByAddons` which I had accidentally left set to 'true', and resetting it to the default fixed the problem. Simple user error, and I'll close the question. Thanks for the help, this pointed me in the right direction.